# using sbt-rjs with play and sbt run

Tags: playframework, requirejs, sbt

I'm using Play 2.3.4, and I've started working on a very badly maintained application (one file controllers and js files with no extra classes).

I wanted to start using requirejs but I've had a lot of problems just to start.

I'm planning to have a one file per module (with require(...)). Something like this:

```
app/assets/javascript/module1/index.js
app/assets/javascript/module2/index.js
app/assets/javascript/module3/index.js
```

1. First question: if I have multiple main modules, what should I set in (it looks for /app/assets/javasctipt/main.js which I don't have) :

   ```
   RjsKeys.mainModule := "..."    
   RjsKeys.modules += JS.Object(...
   ```
2. How to enable sbt-rjs optimization when running 'sbt run' (I can see that optimization is run when sbt start is launched), but not when I launch run (also application takes the orginal .js files so I'm assiming that there is no minimized .js files).

my plugins.sbt looks like this:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("io.teamscala.sbt" % "sbt-babel" % "1.1.0")
```

and my build.sbt looks like this:

```
name := "ble"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,SbtWeb)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  filters,
  "org.webjars" % "rjs" % "2.2.0",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.32",
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.3.1",
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4"
)

pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest)
```

Thanks for your help !